# What might 3-dimensional time look like?(from a hypothetical standpoint?)

Tags: time

I recently started a conworld, and I want it to have a 6-dimensional universe with 3 time dimensions and 3 space dimensions. I think the first dimension would be our standard time. The second might be the timelines of universes with identical spatial laws, but different events occurred. I'm not sure about the third. If I had to guess, it would be worlds with separate spatial laws. I'm happy to hear any changes to the theory.

Comment: Also, those other dimensions might not be "time" in the physical sense.

Comment: [Relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_time_dimensions).

Comment: It sounds like you have your system pretty well thought out.  What more do you need?

Comment: I think I have to close this as primarily opinion based. We don't know, nor do I think we can understand what more dimensions than our own would be like.

Comment: I think we've brought that up before. Try searching for it on *this* Stack Exchange :)  see [here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19745/i-would-like-to-know-if-imaginary-velocity-has-serious-problem/19761#19761)

Comment: Ah, [this one](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35850/multidimensional-time-lines/35913#35913). The search isn't very good; **dimension** does not include posts with **dimensions** !